# Somar valores de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
$qrysel = "select * from won_auctions w left join registration r on w.userid=r.id where payment_date!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'";
```

Essa query vai mostrar uma lista de usuários da tabela **won_auctions** e pegar o nome do usuário na tabela **registration**.

A ideia é que ele verifique quantos registros tem cada usuário na tabela **won_auctions** durante o mês atual, e o total.

A data pode ser verificada pela coluna **payment_date**, e o usuário pela coluna **userid**, da tabela **won_auctions**

No caso:

```
$total_arrematados = xxx;
$total_este_mes = xxx;
```

Eu criei uma tabela e pensei em usar o while para mostrar os resultados, só que preciso que ele mostre apenas uma linha por usuário, e não várias linhas para o mesmo usuário.

Preciso também ordenar para exibir os que tem mais registros por primeiro, para o mês atual.

Estrutura **won_auctions**:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `auction_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `accept_denied` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `won_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `accept_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `payment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `invoice_flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `situacaodescr` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dataenvio` datetime NOT NULL,
  `rastreamento` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lances_creditados` enum('SIM','NAO','REMOVIDO','') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `transacao_ps` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cancelado` enum('SIM','NAO') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NAO',
  `cancelado_motivo` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Estrutura **registration**:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Comment: e cadê a estrutura das tabelas? Quais campos são necessários ? usar `*` com funções de agregação vai ficar complicado. Se possível, acesse o SQLFiddle e monte o banco de dados com algumas informações para facilitar quem tentar te ajudar

Comment: Desculpe a falta de informação, achei não ser necessário. Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: @Victor Na verdade ele vai somar sim, vai pegar todos os valores e somar para me dizer quantos registros existem no total e para o mês atual.

Comment: resolveu o que precisava ?

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo a sua lógica, para contar quantos `won_actions` o usuário teve no mês atual:

```
SELECT
 r.id,
 r.username,
 count(w.id) as total
FROM won_auctions w
INNER JOIN registration r on r.id = w.userid
where month(w.payment_date) = month(now()) and year(w.payment_date) = year(now())
group by r.id, r.username;
```

Para contar quantos `won_actions` o usuário teve no total:

```
SELECT
 r.id,
 r.username,
 count(w.id) as total
FROM won_auctions w
INNER JOIN registration r on r.id = w.userid
group by r.id, r.username;
```

> Porém, eu faria utilizando um sub-select, já que precisa de duas colunas que contam diferentes coisas, e o select parte da tabela de usuários:

```
select
r.id,
r.username,
(select count(w.id) from won_auctions w where w.userid=r.id and month(w.payment_date) = month(now()) and year(w.payment_date) = year(now())) as total_mes,
(select count(w.id) from won_auctions w where w.userid=r.id) as total
from registration r
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/263d8/5 (Sem dados, apenas validando a sintaxe.)